Angular damping being applied to SpriteKit nodes despite setting value to zero
I have implemented a simple pendulum in SpriteKit that I want to continue swinging forever. I've set the angularDamping of all of my physics bodies to 0, but the pendulum still slows down (eventually coming to a complete stop). Here's my code:
// In viewDidLoad

scene = SKScene(size: view.bounds.size)
scene.backgroundColor = .white

let anchor = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 10)
anchor.physicsBody = .init(circleOfRadius: 10)
anchor.position = .init(x: scene.size.width / 2, y: scene.size.height / 2)
anchor.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false
anchor.physicsBody!.angularDamping = 0
scene.addChild(anchor)

let length: CGFloat = 100

let ball = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 5)
ball.physicsBody = .init(circleOfRadius: 5)
ball.physicsBody!.angularDamping = 0
ball.position = .init(x: length, y: 0)
anchor.addChild(ball)

let jointPath = CGMutablePath()
jointPath.move(to: .zero)
jointPath.addLine(to: .init(x: length, y: 0))

let joint = SKShapeNode(path: jointPath)
joint.strokeColor = .black
joint.lineWidth = 5
joint.position = anchor.convert(.zero, to: ball)
ball.addChild(joint)

let pin = SKPhysicsJointPin.joint(
    withBodyA: anchor.physicsBody!,
    bodyB: ball.physicsBody!,
    anchor: scene.convert(.zero, from: anchor)
)
pin.frictionTorque = 0
scene.physicsWorld.add(pin)

let skView = SKView(frame: view.bounds)
skView.presentScene(scene)
view.addSubview(skView)

I've tried setting other friction-related values, e.g: frictionTorque on the SKPhysicsJointPin, but nothing has worked.

Did you try to set the gravity of the physics world to zero? I haven’t tried the code, but it might be worth trying.

I can’t set the gravity to zero because I still want the pendulums to fall. But without any friction, the energy from the gravity should be conserved.

Friction is one component, but gravity still "pulls" the pendulums down. You'll probably have to apply a torque to simulate an engine that keeps the pendulums from stopping.
